# scikit learn sample try out with my classifier and data

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, svm, scikit-learn

I have build a small program that creates a classifier for a given dataset with scikit-learn. Now I wanted to try [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/auto_examples/grid_search_digits.html%5d), to see the classifier at work. For example the clf has to detect "cats".

This is how I go on:

I have 50 pictures of Cats and 50 pictures of "none cats".

1. get descriptors for `data_set` with sift-feature detector
2. Split data into training set and test set (25 pictures cats + 25 pictures non cats = training_set, test_set same)
3. get cluster centers with kmeans from the `training_set`
4. create histogramm data of the `training_set` an `test_set` by using the cluster centers
5. try this code from scikit-learn:

   ```
   tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],
                    'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]},
                   {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}]

   scores = ['precision', 'recall']

   for score in scores:
     print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for %s" % score)
     print()

     clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(C=1), tuned_parameters, cv=5, scoring=score)
     clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

     print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
     print()
     print(clf.best_estimator_)
     print()
     print("Grid scores on development set:")
     print()
     for params, mean_score, scores in clf.grid_scores_:
        print("%0.3f (+/-%0.03f) for %r"
             % (mean_score, scores.std() / 2, params))
     print()
     print("Detailed classification report:")
     print()
     print("The model is trained on the full development set.")
     print("The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.")
     print()
     y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
     print y_true
     print y_pred
     print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
     print()
     print clf.score(X_train, y_train)
     print "score"
     print clf.best_params_
     print "best_params"
     pred = clf.predict(X_test)
     print accuracy_score(y_test, pred)
     print "accuracy_score"
   ```

and I get that result:

```
# Tuning hyper-parameters for recall
()
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py:1760: UserWarning: The sum of true positives and false positives are equal to zero for some labels. Precision is ill defined for those labels [ 0.]. The precision and recall are equal to zero for some labels. fbeta_score is ill defined for those labels [ 0.]. 
  average=average)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py:1760: UserWarning: The sum of true positives and false positives are equal to zero for some labels. Precision is ill defined for those labels [ 1.]. The precision and recall are equal to zero for some labels. fbeta_score is ill defined for those labels [ 1.]. 
  average=average)
Best parameters set found on development set:
()
SVC(C=0.001, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
  gamma=0.001, kernel=rbf, max_iter=-1, probability=False,
  random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
()
Grid scores on development set:
()
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 0.001, 'gamma': 0.001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 0.001, 'gamma': 0.0001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 0.01, 'gamma': 0.001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 0.01, 'gamma': 0.0001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 0.10000000000000001, 'gamma': 0.001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 0.10000000000000001, 'gamma': 0.0001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 1.0, 'gamma': 0.001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 1.0, 'gamma': 0.0001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 10.0, 'gamma': 0.001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 10.0, 'gamma': 0.0001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 100.0, 'gamma': 0.001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 100.0, 'gamma': 0.0001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 1000.0, 'gamma': 0.001}
0.800 (+/-0.200) for {'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 1000.0, 'gamma': 0.0001}
()
Detailed classification report:
()
The model is trained on the full development set.
The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.
()
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0.0       1.00      0.04      0.08        25
        1.0       0.51      1.00      0.68        25

avg / total       0.76      0.52      0.38        50

()
0.52
score
{'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 0.001, 'gamma': 0.001}
best_params
0.52
accuracy_score
```

seems to be that the clf says to all thinks its a cat....but why?

Is the `data_set` to small to get a good result ?

**Edit:** I'm using VLFeat to detecting sift descriptor

Functions:

```
def create_descriptor_data(data, ID):
    descriptor_list = []
    datas = numpy.genfromtxt(data,dtype='str')
    for p in datas:
      locs, desc = vlfeat_module.vlf_create_descriptors(p,str(ID)+'.key',ID) # create descriptors and save descs in file
      if len(desc) > 500:
        desc = desc[::round((len(desc))/400, 1)] # take between 400 - 800 descriptors
      descriptor_list.append(desc)
      ID += 1 # ID for filename
    return descriptor_list

# create k-mean centers from all *.txt files in directory (data)
def create_center_data(data):
    #data = numpy.vstack(data)
    n_clusters = len(numpy.unique(data))
    kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=n_clusters, n_init=1)
    kmeans.fit(data)
    return kmeans, n_clusters

def create_histogram_data(kmeans, descs, n_clusters):
    histogram_list = []
    # load from each file data
    for desc in descs:
      length = len(desc)
      # create histogram from descriptors
      histogram = kmeans.predict(desc)
      histogram = numpy.bincount(histogram, minlength=n_clusters) #minlength = k in k-means 
      histogram = numpy.divide(histogram, length, dtype='float')
      histogram_list.append(histogram)
    histogram = numpy.vstack(histogram_list)
    return histogram
```

and the call:

```
X_desc_pos = lib.dataset_module.create_descriptor_data("./static/picture_set/dataset_pos.txt",0) # create desc from dataset_pos, 25 pics
X_desc_neg = lib.dataset_module.create_descriptor_data("./static/picture_set/dataset_neg.txt",51) # create desc from dataset_neg, 25 pics

X_train_pos, X_test_pos = train_test_split(X_desc_pos, test_size=0.5)
X_train_neg, X_test_neg = train_test_split(X_desc_neg, test_size=0.5)

x1 = numpy.vstack(X_train_pos)
x2 = numpy.vstack(X_train_neg)
kmeans, n_clusters = lib.dataset_module.create_center_data(numpy.vstack((x1,x2)))

X_train_pos = lib.dataset_module.create_histogram_data(kmeans, X_train_pos, n_clusters)
X_train_neg = lib.dataset_module.create_histogram_data(kmeans, X_train_neg, n_clusters)

X_train = numpy.vstack([X_train_pos, X_train_neg])
y_train = numpy.hstack([numpy.ones(len(X_train_pos)), numpy.zeros(len(X_train_neg))])

X_test_pos = lib.dataset_module.create_histogram_data(kmeans, X_test_pos, n_clusters)
X_test_neg = lib.dataset_module.create_histogram_data(kmeans, X_test_neg, n_clusters)

X_test = numpy.vstack([X_test_pos, X_test_neg])
y_test = numpy.hstack([numpy.ones(len(X_test_pos)), numpy.zeros(len(X_test_neg))])

tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],
                     'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]},
                    {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}]

scores = ['precision', 'recall']

for score in scores:
    print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for %s" % score)
    print()

    clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(C=1), tuned_parameters, cv=5, scoring=score)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
    print()
    print(clf.best_estimator_)
    print()
    print("Grid scores on development set:")
    print()
    for params, mean_score, scores in clf.grid_scores_:
       print("%0.3f (+/-%0.03f) for %r"
              % (mean_score, scores.std() / 2, params))
    print()
    print("Detailed classification report:")
    print()
    print("The model is trained on the full development set.")
    print("The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.")
    print()
    y_true, y_pred = y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
    print y_true
    print y_pred
    print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
    print()
    print clf.score(X_train, y_train)
    print "score"
    print clf.best_params_
    print "best_params"
    pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    print accuracy_score(y_test, pred)
    print "accuracy_score"
```

**EDIT:** Some changes by updating the range and savae again the "accuracy"

```
# Tuning hyper-parameters for accuracy
()
Best parameters set found on development set:
()
SVC(C=1000.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
  gamma=1.0, kernel=rbf, max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
()
Grid scores on development set:
()
...
()
Detailed classification report:
()
The model is trained on the full development set.
The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.
()
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

        0.0       0.88      0.92      0.90        25
        1.0       0.92      0.88      0.90        25

avg / total       0.90      0.90      0.90        50

()
1.0
score
{'kernel': 'rbf', 'C': 1000.0, 'gamma': 1.0}
best_params
0.9
accuracy_score
```

but by testing it on a picture with

```
rslt = clf.predict(test_histogram)
```

he's still saying to a sofa: "you're a cat" :D

Comment: You should add code for creating a training/testing sets, as this can be a problem here

Comment: The first thing you should do is `from __future__ import print_function` to get rid of those annoying `()`s.

Comment: yes but i think this is not the problem here ;)

Comment: Which scikit-learn version?

Comment: updated from 0.13 to 0.14

Comment: could you also show us how exactly looks one particular input vector? What are the features values/ranges?

Comment: So it works after changing the range of parameters, as the problem was that the model was not learning at all (assumed everything is a cat) - now is time for a research and optimization, what are the best parameters, best representation etc. do not expect 100% accuracy, in fact it can overfit now, as the matter of fact - size of your dataset is very small, so anything can happen (and by the way, histogram of cat and sofa can be actually very similar, try to visualize your input data and check by yourself). Yet a programming problem seems to be solved.

Comment: well thank you but how can i visualize the data ? by transform the dimensions with pca and plot.scatter it ?! because there are a lot of descriptors in one picture (between 800 - 3000) or should i plot the histograms ? by the way i have found maybe a bug because all histograms of the tested picture looks like [0...0.786...0]!!! all of them ...hmmm

Comment: This is exactly why I was talking about visualizing them (to check if you do not have some implementation bug in the representation). As they are all histograms - and there are just 50 of them - simply plot all 50 histograms and analyze them.

Comment: Well i found a implementation problem in the last predicting "test_picture"...now i've got one question more. Is it useful to plot the results like in this example [KLICK](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_classifier_comparison.html) with the cluster centers etc for analyzation?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities of such behaviour:

- There is an error in creation of the training/testing data [implementation error]
- Training set of 20 element (25 vectors with 5 cross validation leaves 20 for trianing) can be too small for a good generalization [under fitting]
- range of checked `C` and `gamma` parameters can be too narrow - this variables are highly data dependent, your representations' values can require completely different `C`'s and `gamma`'s then those currently used [under/over fitting]

My personal guess (as without the data is hard to reproduce the issue) here is the third option - bad `C` and `gamma` parameters to find a good model.

**EDIT**

You should try **much** bigger ranges of values, eg.

- `C` between `10^-5` and `10^15`
- `gamma` between `10^-14` and `10^2`

  ```
  C=[]
  gamma=[]
  for i in range(21): C.append(10.0**(i-5))
  for i in range(17): gamma.append(10**(i-14))
  ```

**EDIT2**

Once parameters' ranges are corrected, now you should perform the actual "case study". Gather more images, analyze your data representation (is histogram really enough for this task?), process your data (is it already normalized? Maybe try some decorrelation?), consider using simplier kernels - rbf can be very deceptive - on one hand it can get great scores during training, but on the other - fail completely during testing. This is a result of its overfitting capabilities (as for any consistent data set RBF-SVM can achieve 100% score during training), so finding a balance between a model's power and generalization abilities is a hard problem. This is when actual "machine learning journey" begins, have fun!

Comment: I've tried this values with the same results:`"[{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],"C": 10. ** numpy.arange(-3, 4)}]"`.. or do you think i have to look vor bigger/smaller values ?

Comment: I was talking about wider range, not higher resolution. even for such simple data as `heart` dataset, to correctly investigate the model's parameters one has to check much bigger range:
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

Answer (score 3):

> seems to be that the clf says to all thinks its a cat....but why?

It's a bit hard to tell from your pasted output, but it seems this is the second iteration of the loop over `scores = ['precision', 'recall']`, so you're optimizing for recall. That concurs with the classification report, which states that recall is `1.00` (perfect) for the positive class.

When is recall perfect? Well, when there are no false negatives, no cats staying undetected. The easy way to obtain perfect recall is therefore to predict "cat" for every input picture, regardless of whether it's a cat, and `GridSearchCV` found a classifier that does exactly that.

A similar thing can happen when you optimize for precision: perfect precision can be achieved by never predicting "cat" since you'll have no false positives.

To avoid this situation, optimize for accuracy rather than precision or recall, or for Fᵦ if you have a situation with unbalanced classes.

Comment: sounds logical...i will try this out...but what will be the right way if i wanted to analyze the precision and recall of the clf for a given test_set...think i missunderstood the example

Comment: @Linda: then call `classification_report` as you did. Calling a metric function after fitting doesn't change the optimization objective.

Comment: @Linda you should look at precision/recall curve if you want to find balance or use f1_score for a harmonic mean of the two http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html