# sklearn ploting results from SVM classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, svm, scikit-learn

I'm trying to plot my svm classifier results. The "mini-programm" is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210799/scikit-learn-sample-try-out-with-my-classifier-and-data). For plotting I'm going on with [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_classifier_comparison.html) example of scikit-learn. I've modify the code as you can see below. Well i don't know if i'm on the right way because i don't understand when i'm reducing my Data to 2-D if the clusters-centers (between 100 and 300 original data) are reduced too or what happen when i'm trying to take the big "dimensions" and squeeze them into 2-D. Maybe someone could explain it for me ^^

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def reduce_dim(datas):
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    pca.fit(datas)
    data_pca = pca.transform(datas)
    return data_pca

def plotter_plot(kmeans, clf, X, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    names = ["RBF SVM"]
    classifiers = []
    classifiers.append(clf)

    h = .01  # step size in the mesh
    X_r = reduce_dim(X)
    X_train_r = reduce_dim(X_train)
    X_test_r = reduce_dim(X_test)

    figure = pl.figure(figsize=(15, 5))

    x_min, x_max = X_r[:, 0].min() - .5, X_r[:, 0].max() + .5
    y_min, y_max = X_r[:, 1].min() - .5, X_r[:, 1].max() + .5
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

    # just plot the dataset first
    cm = pl.cm.RdBu
    cm_bright = ListedColormap(['#FF0000', '#0000FF'])
    ax = pl.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    # Plot the training points
    ax.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cm_bright)
    # and testing points
    ax.scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c=y_test, cmap=cm_bright, alpha=0.6)
    ax.set_xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    ax.set_ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())
    i = 2
    for name, clf in zip(names, classifiers):
        ax = pl.subplot(1, 2, i)
        clf.fit(X_train_r, y_train)
        score = clf.score(X_test_r, y_test)

        # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
        # point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].
        if hasattr(clf, "decision_function"):
            Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
        else:
            Z = clf.predict_proba(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])[:, 1]

        # Put the result into a color plot
        Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
        ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cm, alpha=.8)

        # Plot also the training points
        ax.scatter(X_train_r[:, 0], X_train_r[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cm_bright)
        # and testing points
        ax.scatter(X_test_r[:, 0], X_test_r[:, 1], c=y_test, cmap=cm_bright,
              alpha=0.6)

        ax.set_xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
        ax.set_ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
        ax.set_xticks(())
        ax.set_yticks(())
        ax.set_title(name)
        ax.text(xx.max() - .3, yy.min() + .3, ('%.2f' % score).lstrip('0'),
            size=15, horizontalalignment='right')
        i += 1

    figure.subplots_adjust(left=.02, right=.98)
    pl.show()
```

is this the right way to fit the "reduce data" again with the clf ? They already have been fit by training and classifying! So is there a mistake or should i fit the 2-D data again ?

Thank you...

Comment: oh hey linda it's you ^^ just saw that after I posted the answer *g*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: what you are trying to do is not possible.
This has been asked a couple of times on SO before.

You can not plot n-dimensional decision surfaces in 2d.
What you could do is just plot the projection of the data in 2d and label them according to their prediction.

There is a plot that does something similar to what you want [in this example](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/plot_kernel_approximation.html#example-plot-kernel-approximation-py).
I am the author of the example but I am not sure the plot has any real meaning. I never use plots like this to inspect my classifiers.

Comment: Hi Andreas I was following the code you reference too... so what's the point of the code then? And what would you recommend as a nice way to show graphically (or approximate - display somehow) a classification surface?  Thanks!

Comment: The code is an attempt of visualization. I would rather try to visualize the labelling of the points and not of the space. You could do manifold learning / pca and just label the points according to their classification. That should be helpful as I said in my original post.

Comment: Thanks Andreas!. PCA is also being done in the code to scatter the plots based on the classes. I guess t-SNE is a good candidate here as well. Cheers.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately we don't have it in sklearn yet. We do have LLE and Isomap, though.

Comment: Just an additional question, is t-SNE support planned sometime? or it would be a good project to contribute?

Comment: There is work in progress: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2822

Comment: @AndreasMueller Hi, please look into this question. How should I change my code usig PCA to plot the hyperplane generated by SVM sklearn https://stackoverflow.com/q/50334915/2508414